# Click event’s `path` property is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a Web-based app using JavaScript for tasks. I lost the ability to delete tasks in all browsers. The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
    at HTMLButtonElement.delItem (script2.js:127:26)
delItem @ script2.js:127
```

Below is the JS file for the application.

```js
// Caching selectors.
const addButton = document.getElementById("enter");
const input = document.getElementById("userinput");
const ol = document.querySelector("ol");
const tasksNo = document.querySelector(".tasks");
const searchInput = document.querySelector(".search");
let todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
const date = document.querySelector(".date");
const doneTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("donetodos")) || [];
// import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

if (todos) {
  todos.forEach((todo) => {
    if (doneTasks.includes(todo)) {
      ol.innerHTML += `
      <div class="list-container">
          <li class="done">${todo}</li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button type="button" class="delete">x</button>
      </div>`;
    }
    else {
      ol.innerHTML += `
      <div class="list-container">
          <li>${todo}</li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button type="button" class="delete">x</button>
      </div>`;
    }
  });
  numberTasks();
  
  const delButton = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
  const li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  
  li.forEach((list_item) => {
    list_item.addEventListener("click", crossItem);
  });
  delButton.forEach((delBtn) => {
    delBtn.addEventListener("click", delItem);
  });
}

function getDate() {
  // Get dates.
  const days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ];
  const monthNames = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];
  const d = new Date();
  const dayName = days[d.getDay()];
  const monthName = monthNames[d.getMonth()];
  const day = d.getDate();
  const year = d.getFullYear();
  
  date.textContent = `${dayName} ${day} ${monthName}, ${year}`;
}

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function numberTasks() {
  if (todos.length === 1) {
    tasksNo.textContent = `${todos.length} task`;
  }
  else if (todos.length >= 2) {
    tasksNo.textContent = `${todos.length} tasks`;
  }
  else {
    tasksNo.textContent = "";
  }
  
  return todos.length;
}

function storeTodos() {
  todos.unshift(input.value);
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}

function createListElement() {
  storeTodos();
  
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  
  div.classList.add("list-container");
  div.innerHTML = `<li>${input.value}</li>
  <button type="button" class="delete">×</button>`;
  ol.prepend(div);
  numberTasks();
  input.value = "";
  
  const li = div.firstElementChild;
  
  li.addEventListener("click", crossItem);
  
  const delBtn = div.querySelector(".delete");
  
  delBtn.addEventListener("click", delItem);
}

function crossItem(e) {
  const list_item = e.currentTarget;
  let listText = list_item.textContent;
  
  if (list_item.classList.contains("done")) {
    list_item.classList.remove("done");
    
    let index = doneTasks.indexOf(listText);
    
    doneTasks.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("donetodos", JSON.stringify(doneTasks));
  }
  else {
    list_item.classList.add("done");
    doneTasks.push(listText);
    localStorage.setItem("donetodos", JSON.stringify(doneTasks));
    Swal.fire("Good job!", "Task completed", "success");
    document.querySelector("body").classList.add("fullheight");
  }
}

function delItem(e) {
  const listItem = e.path[1];
  const listItemContent = listItem.children[0].innerHTML;
  const index = todos.indexOf(listItemContent);
  
  ol.removeChild(listItem);
  todos.splice(index, 1);
  numberTasks();
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}

function addListAfterCLick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
  else {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'error',
      timerProgressBar: true,
      showConfirmButton: false,
      text: "Please enter a task to do",
      toast: true,
      position: 'top-end',
      timer: 2000
    });
  }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
  if (inputLength() === 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'error',
      timerProgressBar: true,
      showConfirmButton: false,
      text: "Please enter a task to do",
      toast: true,
      position: 'top-end',
      timer: 2000
    });
  }
  else if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function searchTodos(e) {
  const input = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const list = ol.querySelectorAll(".list-container");
  
  if (input != "") {
    Array.from(list).forEach((todo) => {
      if (todo.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) === -1) {
        todo.classList.add("hide");
      }
      else {
        todo.classList.remove("hide");
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    list.forEach(list_container => list_container.classList.remove("hide"));
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getDate);
addButton.addEventListener("click", addListAfterCLick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", searchTodos);
```

I have tried other browsers with no luck. I also tried the original code from the developer on his hosted platform and the problem persists. I think this indicates that the browsers are no longer supporting something in this JS file.

Comment: for some reason the line numbers match so that line 127 points at `const listItem = e.path[1];`. The `delItem` function is a callback passed to `addEventListener` so its `e` argument will be set with the `event` value. Is that expected to have `path[1]`?

Comment: A [`MouseEvent`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) doesn’t have a `path` property. Are you trying to use [`composedPath`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath)? If I recall correctly, `Event.prototype.path` is a deprecated, obsolete, or non-standard property. Instead of relying on the index in the path, why not simply use [`e.target`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and [`.closest`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)?

Comment: e.target refers to the element that fired the event. e.target.closest() will return the closest ancestor element that matches the selector passed as an argument. 

In this case, the selector would be '.list-container'. This would give you the list item that the button belongs to. 

So, you could replace the following line:

    const listItem = e.path[1];

with:

    const listItem = e.target.closest('.list-container');